# Read variables from two files and output in a pattern on 3rd file

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, while-loop, exec

I have 2 files like below:

file1:

```
a1,b1,c1,d1,e1,f1,g1,h1
a2,b2,c2,d2,e2,f2,g2,h2
a3,b3,c3,d3,e3,f3,g3,h3
a4,b4,c4,d4,e4,f4,g4,h4
```

file2:

```
x1,y1,z1
x2,y2,z2
x3,y3,z3
x4,y4,z4
```

I want to read simultaneously from both and output the variables in a pattern like below:

```
a1,b1,c1,d1,x1,e1,f1,y1,g1,z1,h1
a2,b2,c2,d2,x2,e2,f2,y2,g2,z2,h2
a3,b3,c3,d3,x3,e3,f3,y3,g3,z3,h3
a4,b4,c4,d4,x4,e4,f4,y4,g4,z4,h4
```

Good news - I've managed to achieve it !!

Bad news - Too many arrays and while loops (too much computation!). I am looking for something simpler as the script will have to read through much data (4k lines and 1M words).

Limitation - BASH shell (probably not a limitation!)

This is what I've done

```
exec 5<file1 # Open file into FD 5
exec 6<file2 # Open file into FD 6

while IFS=$"," read -r line1 <&5
IFS=$"," read -r line2 <&6
do
    array1=( `echo $line1` )
    array2=( `echo $line2` )
    array3=("${array1[@]}","${array2[@]}")
    echo ${array3[@]} >> tmpline
done
while IFS="," read var1 var2 var3 var4 var5 var6 var7 var8 var9 var10 var11
do
    echo -e "$var1,$var2,$var3,$var4,$var9,$var5,$var6,$var10,$var8,$var11,$var9" >> tcomb
done < tmpline

exec 5<&- # Close FD 5
exec 6<&- # Close FD 6
```

Thanks in advance -- I'm waiting patiently :) !!

Comment: I now understand how to edit in this forum.. was struggling from last couple of days to do that .... anyone looking for classes on "How To" ? :) !

Comment: Modified my code a bit.... but still too much computation

while read -r line1 <&5 && read -r line2 <&6
do
stuff..
done
while IFS=","
do
stuff..
done < tmpline

exec 5<&- # Close FD 5
exec 6<&- # Close FD 6

Comment: I'm using this to do the stuff now.. looks simpler, thnx everyone!
--> paste -d , file1 file2 | awk -F, '{OFS=","}{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$9,$5,$6,$7,$10,$7,$11,$8}'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
exec 5<file1 # Open file into FD 5
exec 6<file2 # Open file into FD 6

while IFS=, read -a t <&5 &&
      IFS=, read -a u <&6
do
    echo -n "${t[0]},${t[1]},${t[2]},${t[3]},${u[0]},${t[4]},"
    echo    "${t[5]},${u[1]},${t[6]},${u[2]},${t[7]}"
done >| tcomb

exec 5<&- # Close FD 5
exec 6<&- # Close FD 6
```

Comment: Thanks Edouard.... I think there's a reduction in computation cycles here.. can this be reduced further ?

Also what is the "|" doing at last ??

Comment: the `>|` force overwriting, without need of `set -o nocclober`. I like your `exec`! No other idea to reduce the computation times…

Comment: I've modified ur "echo" part a bit -- echo -e "${t[0]},${t[1]},${t[2]},${t[3]},${u[0]},${t[4]},${t[5]},${u[1]},${t[6]},${u[2]},${t[7]}"  -- hope you like it!

Comment: Modified my script again

    paste -d , file1 file2 > file3
    while IFS=, read var1 var2 var3 var4 var5 var6 var7 var8 var9  var10 var11
    do
    echo -e "$var1,$var2,$var3,$var4,$var9,$var5,$var6,$var10,$var8,$var11,$var9" >> tcomb
    unset IFS
    done < file3

Still on look out for a better one !

Comment: The `IFS=,` value dies with `while`, so `unset IFS` remove the old `IFS` you want to retreive!

Comment: To remove the complexe lines with `echo` you could combine the 2 arrays in a single array and loop on indexes.  It becomes: `v=("${t[@]}" "${u[@]}"); for n in 0 1 2 3 8 4 5 9 6 10; do echo -n "${v[$n]},"; done; echo "${v[7]}"`.

Comment: @Edouard... I didn't get the 'unset IFS' thing that you said earlier.. plz explain!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `paste` to combine the lines of the files. Then, you have to reorder the columns, I used Perl for that:

```
paste file1 file2 -d, | \
    perl -F, -ane 'chomp $F[-1]; $"=","; print "@F[0..3,8,4,5,9,6,10,7]\n"'
```

Comment: I can't use perl.. but I'll still try this out... thnx

Comment: Instead of `perl`, use awk then (it is standard in alla UNIXes): `awk -F , -v OFS="," '{print $1, $2, $9, $3, $4, $10, $5, $6, $11, $7, $8}`.

Comment: @jfgagne, I like ur 'awk' thing... can you please tell me which one will use less computation cycles, ur 'awk' one or 'array' one that I've put up in my comments?... this is kind of important for the script that I'm working on!

Comment: @Marcos: my guess is that `paste` + `awk` will be faster than a single (but complex and sub-optimized) bash, but there is only one way to know it, and it is to test it ;-).  Moreover, do not use temporary files: instead of `paste ... > tmp_file; awk ... tmp_file > final_file` do `paste ... | awk ... > file`.

Comment: @jfgagne, the 'awk' command seems to have missed something. I have added paste + awk ilike this --> paste -d , file1 file2 | awk '{FS=","} {print $1,$2,$3,$4,$9,$5,$6,$7,$10,$7,$11,$8}' | tr -s " " "," -- U'll notice that I've added a "tr -s", as the 'awk' was not sending the output as CSV but as "space separated", my requirement is that the output comes as CSV, but adding "tr -s" doesn't help much as if any of my value as a space( ), it adds comma there.. :( ! Any ideas ?

Comment: @Marcos: `awk -F , -v OFS="," ...`

Comment: @jfgagne, sorry for so many comments... u made a small mistake, hence so many comments... here's the correct paste + awk --> paste -d , file1 file2 | awk -F, '{OFS=","}{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$9,$5,$6,$7,$10,$7,$11,$8}', thnx ! I'll stick to this now !

Answer (score 0):

If you allow yourself to read the files more than once, and using bash process substitution:

```
paste -d , <(cut -d , -f 1-4 file1) \
           <(cut -d , -f 1 file2) \
           <(cut -d , -f 5-6 file1) \
           <(cut -d , -f 2 file2) \
           <(cut -d , -f 7 file1) \
           <(cut -d , -f 3 file2) \
           <(cut -d , -f 8 file1)
```

Comment: I'm afraid I can't use this method.. the data I'm going to work on has many files, with each file containing about 4k lines and ~1M words.. 

PS: I know I shouldn't be using bash! .... but !