# Read from two files line by line and process them simultaneously

Tags: bash

Hello everyone I'm very new to the game so my question is probably rather simple but I'm stuck at this for a long time. I want to process two files from two list of files simultaneously line by line.

I'm trying currently:

```
 read file1 && read file2; 
    do 
    echo "$file1 and $file2"
    done
```

The echo is of course just a spaceholder for the rest of the script but i didn't manage to get any variables out of the read operation.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15461247/1030675

Comment: You are missing the `while` keyword.

Answer (score 13):

You need two separate file descriptors to read from two files at once. One of them can be standard input.

```
while IFS= read -r line1 && IFS= read -r line2 <&3; do
  echo "File 1: $line1"
  echo "File 2: $line2"
done < file1 3< file2
```

Answer (score -1):

```
LINECOUNTER=1
while true; do
    FILE1INPUT="$(sed -n "${LINECOUNTER}p" file1.txt)"
    FILE2INPUT="$(sed -n "${LINECOUNTER}p" file2.txt)"
    echo "$FILE1INPUT and $FILE1INPUT"
    let LINECOUNTER=LINECOUNTER+1
done
```

- The LINECOUNTER variable is just to memorize which line to output next.
- Then you assign the output of the sed command `$(sed ...)` to the
  variable FILE1INPUT. This sed command just reads one line, specified
  by LINECOUNTER from file1.txt. Same with file2.txt
- Then LINECOUNTER is incremented by one, so that the next time sed is
  executed the next line is returned.

Of course one needs an appropriate condition for the while loop to end.

Comment: There is no reason to run `sed` for every line of each file.